# Why is $false -eq "" true?

Tags: powershell

The following code segments output true:

```
$x = ($false -eq "") 
Write-Host $x

$x = ($false -eq 0) 
Write-Host $x
```

Since $false and "" are different data types, shouldn't it automatically equal false?

Comment: In PowerShell 0 length string are evaluated as false. [This](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/12/24/boolean-values-and-operators.aspx) mentions it but im looking for something else.

Comment: If you do `("" -eq $false)` the result is false.

Comment: That is correct. The answer explains why.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

When doing comparison operations, PowerShell will automatically attempt to coerce the object on the right-hand side of the operator to match the type on the left-hand side.

In the case of coercing `[string]` to `[bool]`, any non-null string will evaluate as `$true`, and a null string will evaluate as `$false`. See blog post *[Boolean Values and Operators](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/12/24/boolean-values-and-operators.aspx)* for more information about automatic conversion of different data types to boolean values.

This sometimes leads to unexpected results:

```
PS C:\> [bool]"$false" 

True
```

The string value of `$false` is 'False', which is a non-null string and evaluated to `$true` when cast back to `[bool]`.

It also makes comparison operations non-commutative when the operands are of different data types:

```
PS C:\> '' -eq $false
False
PS C:\> $false -eq ''
True
```

In the first comparison the value `$false` is auto-cast to a string in order to match the type of the first operand (`''`), so you're actually comparing `'' -eq 'False'`, which evaluates to `$false`.

In the second comparison the string `''` is auto-cast to a boolean, again in order to match the type of the first operand (`$false`), so this time you're actually comparing `$false -eq $false`, which evaluates to `$true`.

Comment: thanks for the answer. But when you say "null string" you mean empty string, right? Because a null string and an empty string are two different things.

Comment: Technically they are different things, but either one will evaluate to $false when cast as [bool].

Answer (score 2):

Just sharing one experience here which might be worth noting **when we convert a string value to boolean**:

What I was doing is reading a boolean string value from a configuration file which was getting stored in a variable as shown below:

```
$valueReadFromFile = "false"
```

Now, I wanted to convert it to Boolean value. Since I was not aware of `Convert` class in PowerShell I used casting instead as shown below in a bool condition of `if` block:

```
if([bool]$valueReadFromFile -eq $true)
{
    echo "This message shouldn't get printed in current scenario"
}
```

But I was on a wrong turn. Everytime below message was getting printed because non-empty string in PowerShell gets casted to literal boolean value `$true`:

> This message shouldn't get printed in current scenario

When my program started to behave incorrectly then I explored more and came to know about convert class. I fixed my code as below:

```
$actualBoolValue = [System.Convert]::ToBoolean($valueReadFromFile.Trim())
```