# Why does '$true -eq "string"' returns $true?

Tags: string, powershell, boolean, compare, equals

In powerShell you compare a boolean with a string with the "-eq" operator it will always return the same boolean as I used to compare.

E.g.

```
$shouldBeFalse = $true -eq "hello"
$shouldBeTrue = $false -eq "hello"
```

The variable $shouldBeFalse is $true.
The variable $shouldBeTrue is $false.

I had to use the "Equals" method:

```
$shouldBeFalse = $true.Equals("hello")
```

In this case $shouldBeFalse  is $false.

But why returns the -eq operator with boolean these kind of results?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

PowerShell will always evaluate using the type of the left-side argument. Since you have a boolean on the left PowerShell will try and cast "Hello" as a boolean for the purpose of evaluating with `-eq`.

So in your case `"hello"` is converted to a boolean value `[bool]"hello"` which would evaluate to True since it is not a zero length string. You would see similar behavior if you did the opposite.

```
PS C:\> "hello" -eq $true
False

PS C:\> [bool]"hello" -eq $true
True
```

In the first case `$true` is converted to a string "true" which does not equal "hello" hence false. In the second case we cast "hello" to boolean so the `-eq` will compare boolean values. For reasons mentioned about this evaluates to True.

Another good explanation comes from this answer which might get your question flagged as a duplicate: [Why is $false -eq "" true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26015072/why-is-false-eq-true/26015506#26015506)