# Where Command not Working?

Tags: powershell, where-clause

So I've used the where command a lot with Powershell, but for some reason it doesn't want to work with me in this instance.

```
$blockdata | select userprincipalname, blockcredential | where blockcredential -eq False
```

I simply want to return the items in blockdata that are not blocked (False). 
blockdata has the userprincipalname and blockcredential for multiple people. I tried to only grab users with a 'False' blockcredential when I made the blockdata varaiable, but even therer it wouldn't work"

```
$block = $upns | % {
   Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $_.userprincipalname | select userprincipalname, blockcredential | where blockcredential -eq False
   }
```

I've tried putting quotes around false, but it doesn't help. Still just returns nothing. Can anyone help me out? This is what $block looks like when I out it through the where statement...
[image]

Comment: `False` -> `$False`

Comment: Or `Where {-not $_.BlockCredential}`

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @PetSerAl post an answer

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Is not we have good duplicate target for this? This look like already asked before.

Comment: @PetSerAl probably, let me see what I can dig out

Comment: @PetSerAl Can't decide between [this (exact answer but shameless plugging + not accepted)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33757188/powershell-loop-only-if-condition-is-true) or [this (accepted but incomplete)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26015072/why-is-false-eq-true)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Yes, it is hard decision. How about coin flip?

Comment: @PetSerAl alright, [google says I get to plug my own answer](http://i.imgur.com/RThcNJN.png) :-D