# Matching properties of commands

Tags: powershell, pipeline

I'm trying to hone my PowerShell skills, and as an exercise I'm trying to get all aliases pointing to Get-Content

(note: I'm fully aware that the easy way to do this is simply `Get-Alias -Definition Get-Content`, but I'm trying to do this using pipeing)

My attempt is to run something like:

```
Get-Alias | Where-Object -Property ReferencedCommand -eq Get-Content
```

or

```
Get-Alias | Where-Object -Property ReferencedCommand -eq "Get-Content"
```

but that returns blank.

Running `Get-Alias | Get-Member` reveals that the ReferencedCommand is a `System.Management.Automation.CommandInfo` which could explain why my attempts does not return anything.

Now I don't know where to go from here.

Anyone?

Comment: This `Get-Alias | Where-Object -Property ResolvedCommandName -eq Get-Content` works for me.

Comment: `Get-Alias | Where-Object -Property Definition -eq Get-Content` seems to work as well. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, please read [Why is $false -eq "" true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26015072/why-is-false-eq-true)

The same applies to `Where-Object ... -eq`

```bsh
[pscustomobject]@{ val = 0 } | Where-Object val -eq "" # returns an object
[pscustomobject]@{ val = "" } | Where-Object val -eq 0 # null
```

---

As you've already noticed, the type of the left-hand object is `[CommandInfo]`
while the right type is `[String]`.

Now, there are several way to make your code work.

```bsh
# ReferencedCommand.Name = "Get-Content"
Get-Alias | Where-Object { $_.ReferencedCommand.Name -eq "Get-Content" }

# put [string] in the left
Get-Alias | Where-Object { "Get-Content" -eq $_.ReferencedCommand }

# `-Like` operator casts the left side as [string]
Get-Alias | Where-Object -Property ReferencedCommand -Like Get-Content
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use the -definition parameter.  I've done this a lot.  You can use wildcards and arrays.

```
get-alias -Definition get-content

alias -d get-content


CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Alias           cat -> Get-Content
Alias           gc -> Get-Content
Alias           type -> Get-Content
```